# mPdf deletes all previous files automatically

Tags: php, mpdf

I have been facing a strange problem with `mPdf` in `PHP`. I am creating dynamic pdf files with unique name in my project `downloads` folder which has read/write permission. Everything working fine except sometimes when a file is created all previous files deleted at once. Here is the code -

```
require_once __ROOT_DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __ROOT_DIR__ . '/downloads']);

$recipes = $pdf_data['recipes'];

if(isset($recipes) && !empty($recipes)){
  $pdf_data['recipe_category_info'] = $this->process_recipes_information($recipes);
}

ob_start();
$this->include_file(__ROOT_VIEWS__.'/pdf-template/index.php', $pdf_data);
$template = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$stylesheet = '';

$stylesheet .= file_get_contents(__ROOT_VIEWS__.'/pdf-template/css/normalize.css');
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents(__ROOT_VIEWS__.'/pdf-template/css/webflow.css');
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents(__ROOT_VIEWS__.'/pdf-template/css/pdf.webflow.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($template,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);

$username = $pdf_data['user_info']['fullname'];
$unique_id = $pdf_data['user_info']['unique_id'];

$file_name = $this->process_pdf_file_name($username, $unique_id);

$mpdf->Output(__ROOT_DIR__. '/downloads/'.$file_name.'.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```

What can be the issue that deletes all previous files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your tempDir is equal to your outputDir - maybe mpdf is trying to *clean up the tempDir*? try using another path as tempDir and see if that helps.

Comment: Franz Gleichmann's comment is correct. mPDF cleans up temporary files older than 1 hour in the temp directory.

Comment: Yes, I guess this the issue as so far I see files are not being deleted. I created a root directory and placed the tempDir there.